# Ruby: Blocking HTTP.new.start and dynamic HTTP(S)

Tags: ruby, net-http

I need an application to block an HTTP request so I had to add a couple of lines of code, the only piece I couldn't figure out was the statement `if uri.scheme == 'https'; http.use_ssl = true` is there a way I can set http/https in the current statement:

```
Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start do |http|

  # Causes and IOError... 
  if uri.scheme == 'https'
    http.use_ssl = true
  end

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  http.request(request)
end
```

Added: `IOError: use_ssl value changed, but session already started`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-use_ssl-3D), you cannot call `use_ssl=` after starting the session (i.e. after `start`). You have to set it before, e.g.:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'

http.start do |h|
  h.request Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to change your code to

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

if uri.scheme =='https'
  http.use_ssl = true
end

http.start do
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  puts http.request(request)
end
```

Comment: A mistake while writing the code here...that wouldn't cause an IOError

Comment: You didn't mention any IOErrors, @JordonBedwell. Did you leave out some details from your question?

Comment: @Jordan no I didn't leave out any details, the code comment says "# Causes and IOError..." and that was long before I elaborated it, the question should also highlight the issue.

Comment: @JordonBedwell Ah, my bad. That's what I get for skimming.

Comment: Ok, got it, sorry for my mistake. You have to set use_ssl flag before start http session. I've fixed code snippet above.